# Why Spring security redirects to http by default

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am implementing OAUTH authorization type grant flow. In local, its working fine with http protocol. But when i deployed into openshift environment , tried to hit **https://_______________/oauth/authorize** endpoint to get authorization code, by default its redirects to http. Due to this, am getting **"Network Access Message : The page cannot be displayed"** with **Error code 10060 : Connection timedout** response.

How to redirect login page with https by default in spring security?

Comment: Can you add your project configuration?

Comment: Hi @NatFar , by adding below code in application.properties, my code works fine.

server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto